# Do I lose changes when I upgrade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In extension to this question : [Laravel - login only with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222052/laravel-login-only-with-password)

I am trying to modify in app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php and RegisterController.php and in resources\views\auth the login.blade.php and register.blade.php

If I do modify those files, in the future in case  I upgrade laravel will those changes be kept or I will lose them?
Keeping in mind the question from the other topic, am I on the right path in modifying this files or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other then `vendor` folder, you can modify any files you wish and keep those changes when you upgrade your version.

Everytime when you do uprade or update your composer, based on your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file, new vendor folder will be created and overwrite the existing vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

editing files in `app` or `ressources` folder is always fine, dont worry

But (!) never change files in `vendor` folder

Comment: Beside vendor is any other folder I shouldn't mess with?